# Securing a VB.Net for public release with encryption and possibly ASP.Net API / WebServices

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Apologies, as this is a two part question... boo. I'm not sure what route to go down with securing an app, but I need to determine it now before going to far ahead in the project.

I'm currently in the process of finalising the last few parts of a Windows Desktop VB.Net application.

The application will store potentially sensitive data in a SQL database remotely, which the app will need to connect to, in order to retreive the data.

I previously asked for ways I could help secure the app as much as possible, as it will be deployed in the public domain. I explored encrypting the connection string and sensitive details, as well as obfuscating the code and securing the database to a minimal user who can only execute stored procedures.

My initial theory was:

- Encrypt SQL string in app.config file
- Securely encrypt stored procedure names within code
- Obfuscate / cyptocypher the code so that it's all jumbled and unreadable easily
- Setup a SQL user that ONLY has permission to execute the named stored procedures and remove any other permission (cannot even see tables / system tables etc), so the user would have to know the name of the procedure and the parameters themselves.

My main concern and big fear with this particular setup is that it's still fairly easily hacked. So I guess the first question is...

Option 1: (Least secure) How likely can the above be hacked and what steps am I missing?
How easily could a user decompile the app, painstakingly sift through the obfuscated / cypher'd code, extract the encrypted procedure names and SQL connection string, use the IP to connect through SSMS with the username and password and sit there guessing input parameters of usernames, until a hashed & salted password pops out?

Is there a better way of doing anything above, or am I missing a step above that would dramatically increase the security if I went down this path? I dead read about individual SQL accounts per user but not sure what security benefits this brings?

Option 2: (Most secure) How does a web API or WebService help or work in my scenario?
So this is the option that will of course be jumped on as the way to go, and I'm not against it, but I am a severe novice when it comes to ASP.Net and it's services. So I guess my main question is, is there a guide or at least example of something anywhere I can look at, or even help someone can provide, or even a paid training session, that will show me how I can build such a thing?

Also if an API / WebService can serve data in JSON format for example, how can the WebService accept data as a request to insert into the database? I'm not even sure if this is possible with an API / WebService, as I thought this setup would make it a one-way data transfer.

And if the API / WebService is hosted online and the URL to retrieve this is embedded in the application, how would this be any more secure? Can the end user not simply grab the URL and then send their own requests for data with a lovely GUI to assist them?

Apologies for multiple questions, but I'm very overwhelmed on how to take things forward currently, and given the nature of the data storing, it has to be fairly secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so let's see the options first :

**Option 1**

Firstly, `app.config` is not that secure if the connection string is in pure text. You can actually encrypt part of the config file, which may add more to your security. Next up comes the de-compiling of the code. That's something you can't do mostly anything at all. No matter what level of obfuscation you add to your code or how much you minify it, it will always decompileable. After all, your computer needs to read the code, right? So, yes, obfuscation may increase your app's source code security. However, it won't guarantee 100% security.

And not sure how much experienced are you with databases, but as you said you have a SQL server-end user created that can only execute certain stored procedures, then why are you concerned about someone getting access to your passwords?

And it also makes me wonder why are you worried about hashed+salted passwords. If your app is not generating billions of dollars and you are not ruling the market like Google or Facebook, give me a reason why would i hack into your system? Just to see which skin you have applied to SSMS ?

**Option 2**

Now we're talking! So, if we wanna talk about ***Web API***, let's forget about security first.

Let's say a user, using your desktop app, tries to insert his/her data into the database directly, without any Web API. Suppose when he clicks "***Register***" or something similar, the internet connection of the user drops. You know what happens next? The user opened a connection to your database, tries to insert some data, but before the database can actually get the entire data that needs to be inserted, the app loses connection, your SQL query is either incomplete or became weird, that query gets executed and **BOOM!** The entire table is corrupt! Well, sometimes even worse happens, but hey, let me not scare you anymore.

A ***Web API*** would save you from this. I won't go in detail, but the simplest logic is :

> Either you call the API properly and the API makes database calls, or you don't make a proper call and the API doesn't proceed with a database call.

The API also gives you way more control over what someone can actually get from your servers. You also have a huge advantage when it comes to scalability. Because you make as much updates to your Web API and database without having to do anything with the end user's app, reducing the needs of the user to download each update.

Now, let's get one thing cleared out. Web Service and Web API are two different things(though closely related). Anyways, the request you need to make to get data from the Web API is called a `GET` request. When you want to insert data, you need to make a `POST` request. To delete, you need to make a `Delete` request, to update, you can either go with `PUT` or `PATCH`.

How you server the data on each request is a whole different topic. You can google for that. But i'll make it easy for you. Go with this : [Asp.Net Core 2.0 Web API tutorial](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/35462/creating-web-api-in-asp-net-core-2-0).

Also, do make sure to include "***RESTful***" in your search queries.

Anyways, the best option for you is actually combining ***Option 1*** & ***Option 2***.

1. You can encrypt parts of the connection string
2. Obfuscate the code
3. Make a RESTful Web API
4. Create SQL server-level users with limited permissions.
5. Ensure your sever's security(that's a whole different topic)
6. Monitor incoming/outgoing calls with proper tools and set boundaries.

I guess that's all you can do for now. But if you do have a lot of resources like say, billions of dollars like Google or Facebook, you can add more to your security!

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for this, I just realised I didn't come back and thank you. This was incredibly useful and gave me a really good footing and starting ground to think the right way forward.